# "No module named 'razorpay'" : Django restframework

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, razorpay

```
def provider_factory(code):
  ......
        
        payment_settings = StoreSetting.objects.filter(token='payment').first()
        if code in payment_settings.data['payment']:
            config = payment_settings.data['payment']
    except:
        pass
    ProviderClass = get_class('sales.payment.', snake2camel(code) + 'Provider')
```

[image]

This is my project structure

> > > code = 'razorpay',

Here, through this line "ProviderClass = get_class('sales.payment.', snake2camel(code) + 'Provider')", I am trying to get providerclass, but it cause "No module named 'razorpay"
Give me a solution to fix this

Edit,

```
def get_class(module_name, class_name):
    # load the module, will raise ImportError if module cannot be loaded
    m = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    # get the class, will raise AttributeError if class cannot be found
    c = getattr(m, class_name)
    return c
```

Comment: Remove the dot at the end.

Comment: but still there is an error "module 'sales.payment' has no attribute 'RazorpayProvider'.  and RazorpayProvider is inside payment > razorpay > __init__.py file

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `get_class('sales.payment', f"{code.lower()}.{code}Provider")`. Can you share `get_class`?